# installing and configuring hadoop on ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, hadoop

I'm unable to locate the file `hadoop-ec2-env.sh`.

I've downloaded and intalled hadoop_1.0.4-1_x86_64.deb from http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/hadoop/common/stable/

This is the most recent stable version.

I would like to run hadoop on EC2.

I'm following a tutorial that says: [Edit all relevant variables in src/contrib/ec2/bin/hadoop-ec2-env.sh.](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonEC2)

Where is `hadoop-ec2-env.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be in the [hadoop source location]src/contrib/ec2/bin/hadoop-ec2-env.sh

If you don't know where your Hadoop source location is, use the find command to locate the script.

```
 find / -name 'hadoop-ec2-env.sh'
```

Comment: thank you very much but that i could not find that file

Comment: perhaps hadoop_1.0.4-1_x86_64.deb is the wrong file? should i have downloaded the tar.gz instead? sorry beginner at linux here.

Comment: although when i ran the DEB file with ubuntu software center it said that it was installed succesfully

Comment: You need to install the .deb file first. sudo dpkg -i hadoop_1.0.4-1_x86_64.deb

Comment: i did install the DEB file, the software center says that hadoop is installed

Comment: It looks like you can manually create the file [here](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2011/12/08/no-hadoop-env-sh-in-hadoop-0-23/)